# Scheduled tasks with Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, scheduled-tasks, cron, launchd

What is the best way in Cocoa (and Mac OS X) to schedule a program to be run:

- when the user logs in.
- at certain times of the day (for example: 12:00 noon).
- at certain time intervals (for example: every two hours).

Besides scheduling, it should also be easy to un-schedule the program and not cause errors should the user delete the application.

Essentially the program is a satellite command-line executable placed next to the main application's file within the same `.app` bundle. The program's purpose is to do some background data updates in the user's home directory (within `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp`.)

Is `crontab` a good candidate for this? The `man` page for `crontab` said that the functionality has been absorbed to `launchctl`, but I can't seem to find how to schedule specific times to run the utility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`launchd` is the proper way to do this (`crontab` is deprecated on the Mac in favor of `launchd`).  You'd create a plist file with the information about your program (executable name, arguments, etc), and part of it would be (warning typed in a browser and untested):

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dictionary>
  <key>Hour</key>
  <integer>12</integer>
</dictionary>

<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>7200</integer>

<key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
<string>Aqua</string>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

- The `StartCalendarInterval` should run your program at the top of the 12th hour (so noon).
- The `StartInterval` should run your program every 2 hours (= 7200 seconds)
- The `LimitLoadToSessionType` only loads your program when an Aqua session begins (the user actually logs in to the window server (so this would prevent loading if the user `ssh`'s in)
- The `RunAtLoad` tells the executable to run when the plist is loaded.  This, combined with the `LimitLoadToSessionType`, should start the executable when the user logs in.

It's possible that `StartInterval` and `StartCalendarInterval` are mutually exclusive.  If that's the case, you can take out the `StartInterval` key and change the `StartCalendarInterval` stuff to:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<array>
  <dictionary>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
  </dictionary>
  <dictionary>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
  </dictionary>
  <dictionary>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
  </dictionary>
  <dictionary>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>6</integer>
  </dictionary>
  ...
  <dictionary>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>12</integer>
  </dictionary>
  ...
  <dictionary>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>22</integer>
  </dictionary>
</array>
```

For more information, see `man launchd.plist`.

Comment: This solution is a good choice and in most cases the best. But this is not possible when one needs to create a dynamically configurable task in sandbox mode.

Comment: On changing system date time application get automatically launched even the time didn't match with the plist time

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice GUI app called Lingon which helps with editing launchd configuration files.
You can download it here > [Lingon](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/19879/lingon)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X you can run "crontab -e" in the Terminal to start the crontab editor (Vi by default). When you quit the editor, the job is scheduled.